# Изменить значение TextBox, который находится в ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, mvvm

У меня есть TextBox, значение которого меняется при нажатии на кнопку в VM.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding InputList}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Tag="{Binding AddCalculateCommand}">
```

TextBox, который находится в ItemControl

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Margin="15" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding ValueInVariable}" />
```

```
InputList[index].ValueInVariable = Trunk.Result;
```

Значение изменяется, но на View не отображается пока я не закрою и не открою окно снова

Полный код ItemsControl

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding InputList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Tag="{Binding AddCalculateCommand, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition  Width="3*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="15 5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignSubheadingTextBlock}" Text="{Binding TitleInVariable, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}"   VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="{Binding CalculateRadioButton}" Content="{Binding ButtonContent}" Command="{Binding Tag,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                    AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Margin="15" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding ValueInVariable, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Margin="15 5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignSubheadingTextBlock}" Text="{Binding UnitInVariable}"/>

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

VM

```
  private int i = 0;
       public string ValueInVariable
        {
            get { return calculationDesignModel.ValueInVariable; }
            set
            {
                calculationDesignModel.ValueInVariable = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ValueInVariable");
            }
        }
  public ObservableCollection<CalculationDesignModel> InputList
        {
            get { return calculationDesignModel.InputList; }
            set
            {
                calculationDesignModel.InputList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("InputList");
            }
        }

  public RelayCommand AddCalculateCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return addCalculateCommand ??
                  (addCalculateCommand = new RelayCommand((o) =>
                  {
                      int index = 0;

                      for (; i < InputList.Count; i++)
                      {
                          if (InputList[i].CalculateRadioButton)
                          {
                              index = i;
                              break;
                          }


                      }

                      if (InputList[index].CalculateRadioButton)
                      {
                          OpenTrunkWindowViewModel Trunk = new OpenTrunkWindowViewModel();
                          OpenTrunkWindow ch = new OpenTrunkWindow(new OpenTrunkWindowViewModel());
                          Trunk = ch.OpenTrunk;
                          if (ch.ShowDialog() == true)
                          {
                              InputList[index].ValueInVariable = Trunk.Result;
                              i++;
                          }
                      }

                  }));
            }
        }
```

Model

````
        #region Variables
        private string titleOutVariable;
        private string designationOutVariable;
        private string unitOutVariable;
        private string typeOutVariable;

        private string titleInVariable;
        private string designationInVariable;
        private string unitInVariable;
        private string typeInVariable;

        private int quantityInputList;
        private int indexInputItem;

        private string valueInVariable;

        private string imageFileName;


        private string resultFormula;
        private string result;

        private string formula;

        private bool calculateRadioButton;
        private string buttonContent;
        private string titleAddCalculate;


        private ObservableCollection<CalculationDesignModel> inputList = new ObservableCollection<CalculationDesignModel>();
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string TitleOutVariable { get => titleOutVariable; set => titleOutVariable = value; }
        public string DesignationOutVariable { get => designationOutVariable; set => designationOutVariable = value; }
        public string UnitOutVariable { get => unitOutVariable; set => unitOutVariable = value; }
        public string TypeOutVariable { get => typeOutVariable; set => typeOutVariable = value; }
        public string Formula { get => formula; set => formula = value; }
        public string TitleInVariable { get => titleInVariable; set => titleInVariable = value; }
        public string DesignationInVariable { get => designationInVariable; set => designationInVariable = value; }
        public string UnitInVariable { get => unitInVariable; set => unitInVariable = value; }
        public string TypeInVariable { get => typeInVariable; set => typeInVariable = value; }
        public int QuantityInputList { get => quantityInputList; set => quantityInputList = value; }
        public int IndexInputItem { get => indexInputItem; set => indexInputItem = value; }
        public string ValueInVariable { get => valueInVariable; set => valueInVariable = value; }
        public string ResultFormula { get => resultFormula; set => resultFormula = value; }

        public string ImageFileName { get => imageFileName; set => imageFileName = value; }
        public string Result { get => result; set => result = value; }
        public ObservableCollection<CalculationDesignModel> InputList { get => inputList; set => inputList = value; }
        public bool CalculateRadioButton { get => calculateRadioButton; set => calculateRadioButton = value; }
        public string ButtonContent { get => buttonContent; set => buttonContent = value; }

        public string TitleAddCalculate { get => titleAddCalculate; set => titleAddCalculate = value; }



        #endregion
    ```
````

Comment: А код где? С одним XAML далеко не уедешь. Сделайте минимальный и самодостаточный пример пожалуйста.

Comment: Добавил код VM.

Comment: Почему вы привязываете команду к тегу? Почему бы не привязывать сразу к команде? Я про это место: `Command="{Binding Tag,`, пишите просто `{Binding DataContext.AddCalculateCommand` или где там у вас команда. Также я на вашем месте не делал бы что-то на подобие `get { return calculationDesignModel.InputList; }` Как по мне, лучше сделать событие, которое оповестит о том, что в модели появилось что то новое и в VM его уже обрабатывать. Сейчас вы вечно дергаете коллекцию из модели. Ну и также, давайте код `CalculationDesignModel`, будем смотреть что в нем.

Comment: Простая привязка к команде не работает в ItemsControl, поэтому выполнил ее через Tag.

Comment: Всё там работает, пользуйтесь RelativeSource и всё будет хорошо

Comment: Ну почему тогда у меня работает, а у вас нет? Наверно потому, что вы делаете что-то не так, верно? Хорошо, не суть. Вот ваше свойство `ValueInVariable`, вы его привязали, вы его изменяете, хорошо, но где INPC? От куда View слою знать, что оно обновилось? Вообще в вашей Model все свойства можно заменить на простой `{get;set;}`, зачем выносить приватные поля для этого, если внутри нет какой либо логики?

Comment: но ведь View связана с VM с помощью 
`DataContext = new CalculateViewModel();`

Comment: INPC реализовано в классе BaseModel, который является родительским для моей VM

Comment: Да без разницы где у вас реализован INPC. Вот создайте метод, напишите там вывод какого либо текста, без обращения к этому методу он выведет этот текст?  Также и тут, у вас где-то есть реализация INPC, которая имеет метод `OnPropertyChanged()`, вот его вам надо вызывать внутри `set` свойства, которое будет изменяться через код. Как только вы его вызываете - View слой понимает "Ага, там есть обновления, пойду обновлять интерфейс". Без него, он не получает подобных команд!

Comment: По поводу `DataContext` я что-то не понял, к чему это было сказано...

Comment: но у меня же есть реализация OnPropertyChanged в set свойстве 
```C#
public ObservableCollection<CalculationDesignModel> InputList
        {
            get { return calculationDesignModel.InputList; }
            set
            {
                calculationDesignModel.InputList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("InputList");
            }
        }
```

Comment: А значит при изменении значения должно происходит изменение в View

Comment: Если я в чем-то не прав, приведите, пожалуйста, правильный пример кода

Comment: Ваш код выше будет отвечать только за `InputList = new OvservableCollection...`, только на изменение этого свойство, не более. Вы же, меняете свойство объекта внутри (`InputList[index].ValueInVariable = Trunk.Result;`, а конкретно - `ValueInVariable`. Есть у него INPC? Я не вижу. ВСЕ свойства, которые будут по мере выполнения приложения изменяться программно (через код), должны вызывать INPC!

Comment: что я должен прописать тогда в OnPropertyChanged()?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102031/discussion-between-evgeniyz-and-mark-twain).